# Dúvida sobre o escopo de uma pergunta

Tags: debate, perguntas

Estou buscando uma resposta sobre como fazer determinado procedimento. Que é o seguinte:

1º - Estou buscando uma forma de integrar, uma aplicação **WEB** com maquinas **Físicas**.

Vou citar um exemplo bem simples: Eu clico em um botão na aplicação **WEB** e esta envia de alguma forma(Que não sei qual) um comando para a maquina local, que executa determinado procedimento.

2º -  Depois que o procedimento foi executado na maquina local, ela retorna de alguma for(Que não sei qual) uma resposta de que o procedimento foi executado na máquina.

Minha duvida é: se isso que estou querendo saber, pode ser colocado no site, ou encaixa-se em debate? Ou fora de escopo?

att

Comment: Em geral você descobre depois que posta :) Se a dúvida for exatamente assim, me parece ampla ou não clara. Acho difícil sair alguma resposta só com isso.

Comment: Como seria uma forma considerada, "Boa" de fazer essa pergunta ? No Caso eu iria dar mais alguns detalhes, como as tecnologias que estou usando. O que já tenho, dentre outras informações a mais.

Comment: Não faço a mínima ideia no caso específico, em geral quando a pergunta não está boa, é difícil quem não conhece o que está querendo perguntar conseguir melhorar, a não ser que seja algo pontual, essa falta muita informação. Pelo menos é minha visão no momento. Veja se isto ajuda: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Se souber inglês: https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/

Comment: Podes sempre tentar por no site e ver no que dá.

Comment: Acho válido. Pode publicar. Mas se puder especificar linguagem, ambiente e qual o dispositivo específico, pode ser mais aceito pois alguns podem interpretar como ampla demais ou fora de escopo. Especifique melhor o que é essa "aplicação web". Usa qual linguagem no backend ? (php, asp, jsp, ruby?)

Comment: Fiz a pergunta, http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/157420/37440
Caso não esteja precisando algo e alguém possa me auxiliar a melhora-la estou aberto pra isso

Comment: Quando postou aqui pensei que se referia a "máquina" como se fosse algum dispositivo eletrônico, um robô, por exemplo.. mas na sua questão é "apenas" sobre rede. Eu lembrava vagamente de ter respondido algo bem próximo a isso mas estava difícil encontrar então encontrei aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/149921/comando-cmd-php Mas não sei o motivo de terem excluído a pergunta e as respostas. Eu pedi para reabrir e entender por que foi fechado e excluído... Não entendo certas ações de moderação. Parece que depende da sorte. As vezes uma pessoa aceita e outra pode negar.